# Is glDrawElements() more efficient than glDrawArrays() when there are many duplicate vertices?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to squeeze some performance increases out of my iPhone OpenGL ES application.  According to Instruments, my tiler utilization is near 100% most of the time, and my FPS is about 24.  I'd like to get my FPS up over 30.  I can get there by converting from GL_FLOAT to GL_SHORT, but that presents some fairly daunting technical problems for me at the moment.  I'd rather not go there.

So, I'm considering switching from glDrawArrays() to glDrawElements().  I have 35 meshes made up of 708 vertices, but a lot of those vertices are shared between faces.  I am texture mapping but the mesh is mostly uniform in color.  The faces that require special texturing will be left as is.

Let's say I can cut the number of vertices in half.  Let's also say that I also organize my geometry in a way that makes sense for the iPhone: say, using Imagination Technologies PVRTTriStrip tool.  Ignoring the small amount of extra memory for the index array, that means I've roughly cut the memory bandwidth in half so I should see a fairly nice performance increase.

Is this true, or am I missing or misunderstanding something?  Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I went ahead and tried this, without the PVRTTriStrip tool portion.  All testing was done on an iPhone 3G.  I was able to scale my vertices down from 708 to 113.  And since I'm under 255, I'm using GLubyte as my index type.  So, I went from:

35 * (708 * 32) = ~774K

To:

35 * (113 * 32 + 708 * 1) = ~148K

Which reduced my total memory bandwidth to under 20% of what it was.  My FPS increased to ~34.  So, I saw about a 42% improvement in FPS.  Overall, I'm pretty happy.  I think there's more to be gained, but I have bigger fish to fry now.

Also, I filtered out a bunch of degenerate triangles (not the useful kind) to get my index count down to 522, from 708.  From that I saw an increase to ~40 FPS from the ~34 FPS I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hitting a Tiler Utilization of 100% in Instruments ([like I was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287811/what-does-the-tiler-utilization-statistic-mean-in-the-iphone-opengl-es-instrument)), you're being constrained by the size of your geometry.  Of all the things I tried to improve performance, I only noticed a significant bump in framerate when I reduced the geometry size.  So, yes, if you can eliminate some vertices from being sent, you should see a boost in performance.

Even though you state that it is difficult to do, I highly recommend converting from GL_FLOAT to GL_SHORTs, because you will see a large jump in rendering speed.  I did this in my application, and it wasn't too much of a hassle to implement for the kind of return I got.

Comment: Oh, I whole heartedly agree with you.  I actually had it working at one point, but then I started implementing some new features, and the GL_SHORT conversion was causing me problems.  I backed it out to make progress on the new feature; then, when I went to add it back in, I found a new layer of complexity.  It will definitely be the next thing I try if I find I need to squeeze out more performance.