# Profiling OpenGL ES app on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, glsl, instruments

I'm looking at a game I'm working on in the "OpenGL ES Driver" template in Instruments. The sampler is showing that I'm spending nearly all my time in a function called `gfxODataGetNewSurface` with a call tree that looks like this:

- `gfxIODataGetNewSurface`
- `gliGetNewIOSurfaceES`
- `_ZL29native_window_begin_iosurfaceP23_EAGLNativeWindowObject`
- `usleep`
- `__semwait_signal`

(sorry for the weird formatting, safari or stack overflow is eating my line breaks)

The game is only getting about 40 FPS (on iPhone 4) under what I don't believe is a heavy workload which makes me think I'm doing something pathological with my OpenGL code.

Does anyone know what `gliGetNewIOSurfaceES`/`gfxIODataGetNewSurface` is doing? And what it indicates is happening in my app. Is it constantly creating new renderbuffers or something?

EDIT: New info...

I've discovered that with the following pixel shader:

```
varying vec2 texcoord;

uniform sampler2D sampler ; 
const vec4 color = vec4(...);

void main()                 
{                           
    gl_FragColor = color*texture2D(sampler,texcoord);               
}
```

(yet again my formatting is getting mangled!)

If I change the const 'color' to a #define, the Renderer Utilization drops from 75% to 35% when drawing a full-screen (960x640) sprite to the screen. Really I want this color to be an interpolated 'varying' quantity from the vertex shader, but if making it a global constant kills performance I can't imagine there's any hope that the 'varying' version would be any better.

Comment: The deferred nature of the iOS GPUs makes it a little more difficult to determine hotspots in rendering via Time Profiler and the like. That said, I believe that IOSurface is involved in the transfer of image data, like with the new texture caches in iOS 5.0. Are you working with a lot of textures? Is either your Renderer or Tiler Utilization in the OpenGL ES Driver instrument near 100%?

Comment: Ah I didn't know how to change the different measured statistics before... I'm fairly new to iOS development. Tiler Utilization is very low ~4% but the Renderer Utilization is 100%. According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785640/optimizing-iphone-opengl-es-fill-rate it sounds like I'm fill-rate bound? I'm drawing a couple of full screen RGBA textures and some smaller stuff on top of that. I think I can take it from here. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.