# Error switching from vector<float> to vector<short>

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, objective-c++

I have an app I'm making where I would like to change a vector I'm creating from float to short. My code is in a header file like this:

```
vector<float> vertices;
```

and it works fine, but if I switch it to this:

```
vector<short> vertices;
```

and compile, it crashes with the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1035804: incorrect checksum for freed object
 - object was probably modified after being freed. *** set a breakpoint in
malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have no idea what's going on. If it helps, this is an OpenGL application I'm developing for the iPad.

Comment: If you enable breakpoints, can you get Xcode to report what line the crash occurs on, or obtain a stack trace?

Comment: That's one thing I've never been able to figure out, how do you make XCode output the stacktrace to the log when it crashes?

Comment: @Davido - Why not just look in the appropriate panel to see the stack trace yourself, as well as the current location in your code where this occurs?  In Xcode 4, this happens in the lower debug area that you can show or hide from the toolbar option in the upper-right of the screen.

Comment: The error I posted above is the only thing the debug console output. Is there another setting I can check that will make it show more info? It's never output a full stack trace for me, I don't know if there is something special I have to do to enable it or what.

Comment: If it helps any, it does stop on a breakpoint that gives "SIGBART" in new_allocator.h (one of the built in c++ files, not mine) at: return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));

Comment: @Davido - Looking at this now, when you run with breakpoints on and you hit a stopping point in Xcode 4, switch to the debug navigator (Command-5), and you'll see the full stack trace in the left-hand column within the interface.  If it doesn't have a stack trace there, you could manually set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` like it suggests above, and then re-run the application with breakpoints on.  My Xcode 4 behaviors (found in Preferences) have this navigator automatically be switched to on anything that pauses a run.

Comment: So I haven't figured out why it keeps throwing that error, but I got it working. I just created a new vector of shorts with a different name and it compiles and runs just fine. If I change the type of my variable named vertices from float to short, it crashes, even if I comment out all lines of code that use the variable. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why my app wouldn't run when I changed my vector from float to short, but I solved the problem by creating a new vector object of shorts and using that instead. No more problems and works as expected.