# What is a practical size limit to vertex buffer size?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-array

In OpenGL, you generally get better performance by using vertex buffers, and even better performance by putting many objects into the same vertex buffer, so that lots of vertices can be drawn with a single `glDrawArrays` call.

But, what is the practical upper limit of this?  How many MB of vertex data in the same buffer is too much? At what point should you cut a vertex array into two separate vertex arrays? How do you know this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer could be seen as generic but I guess it is actually dependent on the GPU you are using and the GPU memory available.

There is no hard limit in the number of vertices you can process as per OpenGL specs.

Here you can find some useful information on this topic:

[How many maximum triangles can be drawn on ipad using opengl es in 1 frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175018/how-many-maximum-triangles-can-be-drawn-on-ipad-using-opengl-es-in-1-frame/6205784#6205784)