# How to create cube with rounded corners in cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

I tried to create a cube in Blender and add Bevel modifier(4 segments and width==0.15). Then exported it in pod file. I have got 600 vertices after loading object from POD file in cocos3D. When i added ~500 objects from pod I've got 10fps while objects were in motion by touches. How can I increase a fps? It is possible to create these objects without POD files?

Comment: So, you are wondering why rendering 300,000 vertices on an iOS device is slow? To increase fps you have two options: reduce the number of 3D objects and reduce the number of vertices per object.

Comment: I tried to make a cube with 24 vertices per object. So I have 12,000 vertices in total. On iPhone 4S I got 17 fps for motionless cubes and 10 fps while rotating it by touches. On iPhone 5 30\15 fps.

Comment: Rough ballpark numbers of what *might* be achievable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175018/how-many-maximum-triangles-can-be-drawn-on-ipad-using-opengl-es-in-1-frame
 So it's a little on the slow side but if there's lots of draw calls (does cocos3d have a debug/frame count display?) that might just be expected.

Comment: In **Cocos3D**, you can experiment with the `CC3Performance` demo app to explore performance characteristics. You can add your own models into that app to test them as well.